# How to send selected values to viewModel from multiselect (Kendo MultiSelect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I'm using `Kendo MultiSelect` in my `mvc5` project. So I have a View with `multiselect`:

```
@model Library.ViewModels.Models.BookViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
            placeholder: "--Select Public Houses--",
            dataTextField: "PublicHouseName",
            dataValueField: "PublicHouseId",
            autoBind: true,
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "/book/getallpublichouses"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And I have 2 viewModels:

```
public class BookViewModel
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string AuthorName { get; set; }

        public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<PublicHouseViewModel> PublicHouses { get; set; }

    }



public class PublicHouseViewModel
    {
        public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }

        public string PublicHouseName { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<BookViewModel> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

In my `Kendo MultiSelect` a get all Public Houses from Book controller in JSON format. Next I selected some values:

So, how can I pass this selected values in `public  ICollection<PublicHouseViewModel> PublicHouses { get; set; }` property in `BookViewModel` ?

[image]

Comment: Create your list box using `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.PubHouses, new SelectList(Model.PublicHouses, "PublicHouseId", "PublicHouseName"), "--Select Public Houses--")` and then the script becomes just `$("#PubHouses").kendoMultiSelect();` - no unnecessary ajax call is required. (although your view model should contain a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PubHouses` property, not `ICollection<PublicHouseViewModel> PubHouses`)

Comment: I need to save my selected values in multiselect like a list of PublicHouseViewModel in BookViewModel

Comment: The code I have shown you will bind correctly to your model - i.e. in the POST method, `PubHouses` will contain the values of the selected options! And you cannot get back a list of `PublicHouseViewModel` - a `<select multiple>` posts back an array of simple values - the values of the selected options, not a collection of complex objects.

Comment: Make sure the names of the inputs are the same as the VM BookViewModel for good binding, i can't see the html and the controller, it is a binding problem no kendo or VM only

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`public int[] PublicHouses { get; set; }`

instead of:

```
 public  ICollection<PublicHouseViewModel> PublicHouses { get; set; }
```

Or you can create a new field in `BookViewModel` only for posting.
When you are posting values from kendoMultiSelect, he posts only `"dataValueField"`. After you post only id's you can do the rest of the logic in POST action.

It depends how you implemented your `POST` action and also on the relationship between two tables: Is it `1...N`, or `N....N`.